# Ajax call to PHP migrating from Javascript to Node.js and Express

Tags: php, ajax, node.js, express, parse-platform

novice web developer here.

Right now I have an app that takes information from a page presented to the user, and does an ajax call with this information to some PHP code that runs an algorithm and returns an answer.

The front end code is written in vanilla html, and Javascript (with jQuery) for the ajax call.  Everything is sitting on the same machine.

Now I'd like to change the design: I want to keep all the PHP code exactly the same on my machine, but I'd like to migrate the front end code from vanilla html/javascript to Parse.com's "Cloud Code", which is apparently a Node.js framework called Express.  So the physical locations of the code will also change: the PHP algorithms will sit on my machine, but what is being served to the user now sits on Parse.com.

I can't make the same ajax calls from jQuery in the Cloud Code because I assume I would run into the [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).  I also don't really want to make the calls from Javascript because I no longer want this information to be available to view on the browser: I want to take data straight from the Parse database, pass it to my PHP code, then have it return an answer so that I can display *that* to a user.  All the way up to displaying an answer to the user, I want this data hidden from the user so he doesn't know what is being grabbed from the Parse DB, or what data is being passed to my server.

At the risk of sounding ignorant, what do I have to do to get the server side Express code to talk to a remote PHP library, send data to it and receive an answer, then display that to the user in a completely ajax manner?  Is it even possible?

Before suggesting, I can't get rid of the PHP bit, because it wraps around a heavy-duty image processing library called [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) ([Imagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) is the PHP extension).

Comment: PHP APi + request module for node. you should be OK.

Comment: As far as turning my PHP code into an API, is it pretty straight forward?  Some cursory googling led me to this, which doesn't look bad: https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2015/10/creating-a-simple-rest-api-in-php/

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following, but are you now going to have 2 severs for your code? (remember, Node.js is a server-side technology). I'm not 100% sure of your goal, but you *could* use your PHP code as a proxy to the Parse server. BTW - if a proxy isn't appealing, you can make CORS calls with jQuery AJAX using JSONP.  I wrote an example of using JSONP:https://github.com/RichBuff/PhoneGap-App-with-JSONP-AJAX-Call/blob/master/ajaxdemo.html.  It's not exactly what you want, but you can find many other examples.

Comment: @richb01 that's correct. One hosts the site the user visits, and the other server is solely used for calling my PHP code.  I'm trying to figure out the correct way to pass data to the PHP on that lonely server, and return data back to the server hosting the site.

I'll look at your guides.  Thank you.

Comment: So...If I'm picturing your layout correctly, you user's site is hosted by Parse.com (node.js). You want to call PHP from Node.js. Assuming I'm correct, you can always make HTTP calls to your PHP server from Node. (Probably why you are asking about how to make your PHP RESTful. :-) ).  I don't have a PHP server running, so I can't quickly write an example.

Comment: Yeah, it's okay, I don't need a direct example, I'm just trying to fill in the gaps between what I do know and don't.


For example, right now, I do a jquery .ajax call to my php code from my js code. On the php side, I get the data that I passed to it, manipulate it, then `echo` json encoded data back.

But now, I'm curious how I can do this from node.js (or Express), in a sort of drop-in manner. I don't think I can leave my php code as is because since it's on a different server, I would run into the same-origin problem. And also, I don't know how to do this in node.js in general.